# Reducing size of a character array in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given a character array:

```
In [21]: x = np.array(['a     ','bb   ','cccc    '])
```

One can remove the whitespace using:

```
In [22]: np.char.strip(x)
Out[22]: 
array(['a', 'bb', 'cccc'], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

but is there a way to also shrink the width of the column to the minimum required size, in the above case `|S4`?

Comment: Is `np.char` new?  My version (1.3.0) doesn't have anything in `char` except `chararray`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to change the data type?

```
import numpy as NP
a = NP.array(["a", "bb", "ccc"])
a 
# returns array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], dtype='|S3')
a = NP.array(a, dtype="|S8")   # change dtype
# returns array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], dtype='|S8')

a = NP.array(a, dtype="|S3")   # change it back
# returns array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], dtype='|S3')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = np.array(['a     ','bb   ','cccc    '])
>>> x = np.array([s.strip() for s in x])
>>> x
array(['a', 'bb', 'cccc'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```